Using a class to open same popup using document.querySelector
I have a popup login box on my site, I use <a class="logincontent">Login</a> which then calls up this function:
document.querySelector('a.logincontent').onclick = () => {  
    basicLightbox.create(`
        <section>
            MY POPUP HTML CODE SITS IN HERE
        </section>
    `).show()
}

This works fine but I have the login button on multiple places on my site on the same page and I want it to call the same popup. From research I need a loop allow the multiple classes call the same function but all my attempts to get this to work have failed. If anyone can help me understand how I can achieve this that would be great?
I tried using the suggestions on this site https://dev.to/baransel/how-to-add-an-event-listener-to-multiple-elements-in-javascript-aco but I was unable to use this logic with my code.
Thanks
Eddie

Be aware that Stack Overflow supports markdown, so you can put your code in code blocks

Why not define a function like bindPopUp that add the event listener, and call it with every login button you have?

You can achieve this either by using multiple selectors as shown below:
document.querySelectorAll('a.logincontent').forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = () => {
        basicLightbox.create(`
            <section>
                MY POPUP HTML CODE SITS IN HERE
            </section>
        `).show()
    }
});

Or you could store the popup html in a variable to make it more maintainable:
const loginPopupContent = `
    <section>
        MY POPUP HTML CODE SITS IN HERE
    </section>
`;

document.querySelectorAll('a.logincontent').forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = () => basicLightbox.create(loginPopupContent).show()
});

Changes I made to the code are:

Using querySelectorAll() instead of querySelector() to select all matching elements
Using forEach() to attach the click handler to each button
Alternatively storing the popup html in a variable to avoid repetition

Make sure all your buttons have the logincontent class:
<a href="#" class="logincontent">Login</a>
<a href="#" class="logincontent">Login Here</a>
<!-- etc -->


Thanks so much, works perfectly!
